# Is it possible to tell luis to extract an specific value from a given text?

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

i want to create an chat bot which can track packages (and many things more). I'm kinda new to all these intents and entities things. My goal to achive is that if i say to the chatbot "track the package [PACKAGEID]" or "could you please find [PACKAGEID] for me?" and than luis should return the intent and the [PACKAGEID]. Is this possible? Or if not, is there something else i can use (best would be if this is from microsoft, because of business stuff... yay)

kind regards,
me.... hey!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement, you can try the following steps:

1)Add a simple entity named **PackageID**

2)Add a [phrase list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-feature) for PackageID(s)

[image]

3)Add a intent named **FindPackage** and add some example utterances, and then label entity in utterance.

[image]

4)Train (and publish) the app

***Test result:***

[image]

***Note:***

> I'm kinda new to all these intents and entities things.

You can get more information about key concepts of LUIS app in [LUIS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/home).

Answer (score 0):

If you know all possible formats of the "PACKAGEID" then you may use Entity of type "Regex"

1) click at [image]

2) Create Regex definition. Example below matches all PACKAGEID-s

starting by "KQ" then followed by 8 to 10 numbers, ending by "DE"

[image]

3) If you try sentence "*could you please find kq123456789de for me?*" then you get following result

```
{
  "query": "could you please find kq123456789de for me?",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Status",
    "score": 0.9369452
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Status",
      "score": 0.9369452
    },
    ...
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "kq123456789de",
      "type": "PACKAGEID",
      "startIndex": 22,
      "endIndex": 34
    }
  ]
}
```